# LPC2148 baud rate equation

Tags: arm, lpc

I'm little confused about the baud rate calculating equation of LPC2148

In data sheet equation is

[image]

[image]

But in every tutorial I could find

equation is

[image]

Second equation sets the baud rate as required.

Am I missing something?

Tutorials that I checked

1. [Link1](http://www.ocfreaks.com/lpc2148-uart-programming-tutorial/)
2. [Link2](https://embetronicx.com/tutorials/microcontrollers/lpc2148/lpc2148-serial-communication-tutorial/)
3. [Link3](http://binaryupdates.com/uart-in-lpc2148-arm7/)

Comment: I have no experience with LPC2148, but equations are same if U0 stand for oversampling which is usually 16 (or 8 with faster baud rates).

Comment: @Rokta Here U0 stands for UART0, U0DLL & U0DLM are device latch registers of UART0

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that makes sense is that the equation in the datasheet has an error.

That same datasheet says:

> The U0DLL and U0DLM registers together form a 16 bit divisor where U0DLL contains the lower 8 bits of the divisor and U0DLM contains the higher 8 bits of the divisor

That suggests it should be `256*DLM+DLL` as written in tutorials. In example tables below, it's also treated as 16-bits altogether (upper 8 + lower 8).

Note that April 2012 version of datasheet [1] contains the corrected equation.

[1] https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10139.pdf

Comment: I gave DLM = 1, DLL = 97, MULVAL = 14 & DIVADDVAL = 1, If equation was the one with 16 in denominator, Calculated baud rate would be 7743, and Equation with 256 in denominator would give 2478. I checked the value in Keil debugger, and the answer is 2478. So equation with 256 is the right one.

Comment: Can you tell me how you got the denominator as 256 by the info of U0DLL & U0DLM

Comment: Upper 8 bits means `1<<8` or `2**8`, which is 256.